# I can't run dev server in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I use a `webpack-simple` template with **vue-cli** but after install when i try to

> npm run serve

this error code exists.

```
C:\Users\Utku\Desktop\workarea\vuejs\vue-cli-intro\node_modules\depd\index.js:399
    throw new TypeError('argument fn must be a function')
    ^

TypeError: argument fn must be a function
    at Function.wrapfunction [as function] (C:\Users\Utku\Desktop\workarea\vuejs\vue-cli-intro\node_modules\depd\index.js:399:11)
    at populateConstructorExports (C:\Users\Utku\Desktop\workarea\vuejs\vue-cli-intro\node_modules\http-errors\index.js:264:45)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Utku\Desktop\workarea\vuejs\vue-cli-intro\node_modules\http-errors\index.js:30:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:683:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Utku\Desktop\workarea\vuejs\vue-cli-intro\node_modules\send\index.js:15:19)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! vue-cli-intro@1.0.0 dev: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the vue-cli-intro@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
``
```

Comment: Could you paste the code you use to run the dev server

Comment: can you show your scripts on your `package.json` file

Comment: Code is npm run serve

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "name": "vue-cli-intro",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
    "vue": "^2.6.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.9.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.9.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.9.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "rules": {},
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    }
  },
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "autoprefixer": {}
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with uninstalling nodejs and reinstalling latest stable version of it.